# Store URL to image directly in DB (without Carrierwave uploader)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm currently developing an application with Ruby on Rails where I use the carrierwave-Gem. If I choose an Image from my computer and save the model, everything works as expected.

But now, I want to store the images-Url directly in the DB without using carrierwave at all (also no remote upload). I just want to store the image-Url I get from an external API in the field where I normally store the Image (with the help of Carrierwave).

Here's my current approach, which fails to store the image-Url:

```
def create_with_api
  @job = Job.friendly.find(request.env['omniauth.params']['job_id'])
  auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  @applicant = @job.applicants.new(
    is_male: auth.extra.raw_info.gender == 'm' ? true : false,
    first_name: auth.extra.raw_info.first_name,
    last_name: auth.extra.raw_info.last_name,
    street: auth.extra.raw_info.business_address.street,
    zip_code: auth.extra.raw_info.business_address.zip_code,
    city: auth.extra.raw_info.business_address.city,
    education: 'other',
    telephone: auth.extra.raw_info.business_address.phone,
    email: auth.extra.raw_info.active_email,
    birthday: Date.new(auth.extra.raw_info.birth_date.year, auth.extra.raw_info.birth_date.month, auth.extra.raw_info.birth_date.day),
    passport_photo_url: auth.extra.raw_info.photo_urls.large
  )

  raise @applicant.to_json
 end
```

And this is the the stuff which is displayed when the exception is raised:

```
{"id":null,"is_male":true,"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","street":"Foo bar street 123","zip_code":"12345","city":"Johnscity","telephone":"12345678","email":"foo@bar.de","birthday":"2012-12-13","job_id":9,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"education":"other", "passport_photo_url":{"url":null}}
```

It seems that I need to do something like

```
passport_photo_url: { url: 'http://www.example.com/image.png' }
```

But that fails silently as well.

Any suggestions

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems like auth.extra.raw_info.photo_urls.large is returning `{url:null}` so you need to check your auth hash first for the real path to the url you want to store.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Thanks for you comments @SarpKaya I haven't solved the issue. I've ditched Carrierwave and now I'm using just a plain string-Field in the database.